# Android getting time and date in specified format

Tags: android, date, time, calendar, formatting

I am using following code to display date and time:

`String currentDateTime =java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

textViewDay.setText(currentDateTime);`

I am getting date and time in format

Sep 17,2012 1:24:31 PM

I don't want to display the second's in output,so how yo get the output in following format

Sep 17,2012 1:24 PM

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a `SimpleDateFormat`:

with this pattern:

```
String pattern = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat to format you string accordingly:-

```
Date d=new Date("Sep 17,2012 1:24:31 PM");// Your date to be formatted
          String strDateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy h:mm a";
             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

             System.out.println(sdf.format(d));// The result required
```